# hacluster with galera-cluster

Tags: juju, high-availability

I am trying to build a HA mysql using the following charms

- https://jujucharms.com/galera-cluster/trusty/1
- https://jujucharms.com/hacluster/trusty/27

I start 3 units of galera-cluster in separate VM each using the following configuration in order to deploy the service (galera-cluster)

`galera-cluster:
  vip: '10.3.0.101'
  sst-password: root
  root-password: root`

A fragment of the log is the following saying that is cannot assign requested address although the ip address is configured according my network configuration:

```
2016-02-22 15:46:05 INFO juju-log hanode:36: Missing required configuration: []
2016-02-22 15:46:05 INFO juju-log hanode:36: Unable to configure corosync right now, deferring configuration
2016-02-22 15:46:07 INFO juju-log ha:38: Missing required configuration: ['corosync_mcastport', 'corosync_bindnetaddr']
2016-02-22 15:46:07 INFO juju-log ha:38: Unable to configure corosync right now, deferring configuration
2016-02-22 15:46:08 INFO juju-log hanode:36: Missing required configuration: ['corosync_mcastport', 'corosync_bindnetaddr']
2016-02-22 15:46:08 INFO juju-log hanode:36: Unable to configure corosync right now, deferring configuration
2016-02-22 15:46:10 INFO juju-log ha:38: Missing required configuration: ['corosync_mcastport', 'corosync_bindnetaddr']
2016-02-22 15:46:10 INFO juju-log ha:38: Unable to configure corosync right now, deferring configuration
2016-02-22 15:46:11 INFO juju-log hanode:36: Missing required configuration: ['corosync_mcastport', 'corosync_bindnetaddr']
2016-02-22 15:46:11 INFO juju-log hanode:36: Unable to configure corosync right now, deferring configuration
2016-02-22 15:46:13 INFO juju-log hanode:36: Missing required configuration: ['corosync_mcastport', 'corosync_bindnetaddr']
2016-02-22 15:46:13 INFO juju-log hanode:36: Unable to configure corosync right now, deferring configuration
2016-02-22 15:46:21 INFO ha-relation-changed Traceback (most recent call last):
2016-02-22 15:46:21 INFO ha-relation-changed   File "/var/lib/juju/agents/unit-galera-hacluster-2/charm/hooks/ha-relation-changed", line 424, in <module>
2016-02-22 15:46:21 INFO ha-relation-changed     hooks.execute(sys.argv)
2016-02-22 15:46:21 INFO ha-relation-changed   File "/var/lib/juju/agents/unit-galera-hacluster-2/charm/hooks/charmhelpers/core/hookenv.py", line 691, in execute
2016-02-22 15:46:21 INFO ha-relation-changed     self._hooks[hook_name]()
2016-02-22 15:46:21 INFO ha-relation-changed   File "/var/lib/juju/agents/unit-galera-hacluster-2/charm/hooks/ha-relation-changed", line 169, in ha_relation_changed
2016-02-22 15:46:21 INFO ha-relation-changed     if not get_corosync_conf():
2016-02-22 15:46:21 INFO ha-relation-changed   File "/var/lib/juju/agents/unit-galera-hacluster-2/charm/hooks/utils.py", line 214, in get_corosync_conf
2016-02-22 15:46:21 INFO ha-relation-changed     'corosync_bindnetaddr': bindnetaddr(bindiface),
2016-02-22 15:46:21 INFO ha-relation-changed   File "/var/lib/juju/agents/unit-galera-hacluster-2/charm/hooks/utils.py", line 130, in get_network_address
2016-02-22 15:46:21 INFO ha-relation-changed     network = "{}/{}".format(get_iface_ipaddr(iface),
2016-02-22 15:46:21 INFO ha-relation-changed   File "/var/lib/juju/agents/unit-galera-hacluster-2/charm/hooks/utils.py", line 106, in get_iface_ipaddr
2016-02-22 15:46:21 INFO ha-relation-changed     struct.pack('256s', iface[:15])
2016-02-22 15:46:21 INFO ha-relation-changed IOError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
2016-02-22 15:46:21 ERROR juju.worker.uniter.operation runhook.go:107 hook "ha-relation-changed" failed: exit status 1
```

and the status of the galera-hacluster subordinate service is

```
hook failed: "ha-relation-changed" for galera-hacluster:ha
```